# MS- Access query for total hours and time deduction

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I need to perform a time sheet calculations  Employee will punch in and punch out. I store those records in one table. That table has time and a field for in punch or out punch. Employee may go out for lunch or other reasons and punches for out and in. I need to deduct those times and get the working hours. My table will look like below :

```
PunchTime  EmpCode    IsInpunch
10:01 AM   (A)        T
12:03 PM   (A)        F            (this isoutpunch) 
01:05 PM   (A)        T
07:14 PM   (A)        F
10:32 AM   (B)        T
```

For (A)'s time 7.14 - 10.01 is the total hours, but he was not there between 12.03 to 01.05 so I need to deduct the lunch time and get the total hours. How to do this in Query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward.  Assuming your T and F IsInPunch is balanced, which is to say for any day, you will have T-F or T-F-T-F etc (always paired), just total up the F and subtract the total of T's.

```
select empcode, DateValue(PunchTime),
    sum(IIF(IsInPunch='F',PunchTime,0)) -
    sum(IIF(IsInPunch='T',PunchTime,0))
from TimeSheet
group by empcode, DateValue(PunchTime)
```

(haven't got Access open but do check the syntax)

Comment: Hi Cyberkiwi, Thanks for you solution It worked perfectly...!